# How to know has a product an image

Tags: magento

In which table i can understand has a product an image or not. This is need to do with `mysql queryes`, not `magento models`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table you get information about product image

Please check image

[image]

Simple mysql query for getting image from databse is

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql= "Select value from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE entity_id=1";
    $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Where `entity_id` is a `propductId`

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: But some trouble in this table i am can't find rows with empty `value`, so i need check all products and get product without image. Thanks!

Comment: product without image dosent store in this table means when you call $product->getImageUrl() you get no_selection

Answer (score 0):

Also with magento

```
<!--
<?php
$products123321 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection');

foreach($products123321 as $product123321)
{
    echo  $product123321->getSku() . " has no image \n<br />\n";
    //var_dump($product->getData()); //uncomment to see all product attributes
                                     //remove ->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection');
                                     //from above to see all images and get an idea of
                                     //the things you may query for
}       
?>
-->
```